# sql distinct on multiple cols but not all the columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

I am trying to write a merge query to read some data from table A and merge in table B.

While reading from A , I want to make sure that the rows are distinct based on few columns. so I have a query something like:

select distinct col1, col2, col3 from A. 
However I want the uniqueness to be on (col1,col2) pair. The above query would still get me rows which are unique for (col1,col2,col3) but not for (col1,col2)

Is there any other way to achieve this or use something like
select distinct(col1,col2),col3 from A.

Also, 
I expect that A would have many records ~10-20 million . Moreover I am planning to iterate over multiple such table A [which itself is generated on the fly over few joins]. Hopefully the performance would be not worse of the solution, but in either case I am looking for a solution that works first and then I might run queries in part.

Oracle 10G is the version.

Thanks !

Update: I am wondering if groupby would invoke a sorting operation whcih would be very expensive than using distinct ?

Update: Answering one of the question below : With (A, B, C) and (A, B, D) rows, what is your expected result? 
=> Assuming I want distinct on (A,B) it is fine to return either of (A,B,C) or (A,B,D) but not both.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to get. If you have (A, B, C) and (A, B, D), which row should your query return? Or do you only want it to return cases where (col1, col2) is unique?

Comment: wont groupby req all the 3 columns col1, col2, col3

Comment: please, reply to @eaolson in order to suggest a solution for you. With  (A, B, C) and (A, B, D) rows, what is your expected result?

Comment: @danihp  .. I have answered your questions. Thanks for the help

Comment: Then, @michalpowaga answer Is right.

Answer (score 1):

If there more then one distinct value in `col3` for specific pair (`col1`, `col2`) you'll have to choose one of them I've used here `max` (but you can use any of those [Aggregate Functions (Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#sthref961)):

```
select col1, col2, max(col3) 
from A 
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: I dont want, max(col3) .. basically this select would be used to "insert into a diff table" .. so max(col3) would not be acceptable .. I want rows => distinct(col1,col2),col3

Comment: @codeObserver, you wrote "Assuming I want distinct on (A,B) it is fine to return either of (A,B,C) or (A,B,D) but not both." it sounds like it doesn't matter what you get `C` or `D` (`max` ensure this) and now you say that it does. So please explain the rule behind it (there must be something).